# select multiple rows group by date interval ( causes duplicates)

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to retrieve weight data summed over the first 15 days of a month and another 15 days of that month.
Like the table below .

[image]

here is my code,

```
SELECT  * from

( select SUM(B.SCALE_WEIGHT) as Mtrl1 FROM TRACK2.LOG2_TAB B 
where   B.SCALE_EVENTDATE >= date '2020-09-01' 
and B.SCALE_EVENTDATE < date '2020-09-30' 
AND B.Scale_EVENTDATE = B.SCALE_EVENTDATE 
and MTRLID_EXT = 206
group by  floor(extract(day from SCALE_EVENTDATE)/16)   )  ,


( select SUM(B.SCALE_WEIGHT) as Mtrl2 FROM TRACK2.LOG2_TAB B 
where   B.SCALE_EVENTDATE >= date '2020-09-01' 
and B.SCALE_EVENTDATE < date '2020-09-30' 
AND B.Scale_EVENTDATE = B.SCALE_EVENTDATE 
and MTRLID_EXT = 211 
group by  floor(extract(day from SCALE_EVENTDATE)/16)   )
```

but the result is shown in the image below, the data is duplicated ! and missing Date column

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and show the definition of  TRACK2.LOG2_TAB and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    floor(extract(day from scale_eventdate)/16) as fortnight,
    sum(case when mtrlid_ext = 206 then scale_weight else 0 end) as mtrl1,
    sum(case when mtrlid_ext = 211 then scale_weight else 0 end) as mtrl2
from track2.log2_tab
where   
    mtrlid_ext in (206, 211)
    and scale_eventdate >= date '2020-09-01' 
    and scale_eventdate <  date '2020-10-01' 
group by  floor(extract(day from scale_eventdate) / 16)
```

Note that I fixed the date filtering; if you want the entire month of September, then the second condition should be: `< date '2020-10-01'`.